# How to get an object with transaction in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have a Service class like this:

```
@Service
public class CompanyServiceImpl implements CompanyService {

    @Autowired
    private CompanyDAO companyDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void addOrUpdateCompany(Company company) {
        companyDAO.addOrUpdateCompany(company);
    }

}
```

Normally, I can have an instance of CompanyService from Spring by:

```
@Autowired
CompanyService companyService;
```

But, in some cases, I want to create/get an instalce of CompanyService without @Autowired like this:

```
CompanyService companyService  = XXX.getxxx("CompanyService");
```

Is there any ways I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other way is

```
@Component
public class ContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        CONTEXT = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return CONTEXT;
    }
}
```

And then

```
CompanyService service = ContextHolder.getContext().getBean(CompanyService.class);
```

Comment: This is more clear http://jerlinworld.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/making-your-spring-application-context-aware/  but I give you as the answer anyways.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you mean something like - [**ServiceLocatorFactoryBean**](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.html)
with it you can call somthing like `MyService getService(String id))`.

Another way, will be to implement some kind of a controller service that will have all other services autowired to it, and will hold a map from their string id to actual instances.

In my opinion the second option is better, since it's more manageable and clear.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: thanks, if it could have one more answers, I would also vote yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. You need to instancate the application context and then get your been.

```
Resource res = new FileSystemResource("beans.xml");
XmlBeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(res);
```

or

```
ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource("beans.xml");
XmlBeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(res);
```

or

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
    new String[] {"applicationContext.xml", "applicationContext-part2.xml"});
// of course, an ApplicationContext is just a BeanFactory
BeanFactory factory = (BeanFactory) appContext;
```

and use:

```
MyObject my = (MyObject)factory.getBean(NAME_OF_YOUR_BEAN);
```

Comment: thanks, if it could have one more answers, I would also vote yours.